# Firebase to Kotlin Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to retrieved selected data in Firebase to a fragment in Kotlin? Not all data only selected row.

I'm new to Kotlin. Please help me.

firstly user login to the system. for this I checked the user name from Firebase. it works properly. But after that, I want to retrieve data of that username into a fragment. In one activity I add five fragments. I need to load all data of that user into one Fragment.

for example in this abi is a username and I need to load all data of only that username into one fragment.

Firebase data
[image: Firebase data]

Inside of abi
[image: Inside of abi]

here's what I added.

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val userRef = rootRef.child("User").child(sessionId)
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                val name = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String::class.java)
                val age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String::class.java)
                val phone = dataSnapshot.child("phoneNo").getValue(String::class.java)
                val bank = dataSnapshot.child("bankAccNo").getValue(String::class.java)
                val password = dataSnapshot.child("passwordRegister").getValue(String::class.java)
                    nameText.setText(name)
                    ageText.setText(age)
                    phoneText.setText(phone)
                    bankText.setText(bank)
                    passwordText.setText(password)

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage())

            }
        }
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selected data"? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: Ok, show us the content of your `abi` node as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from the Firebase Realtime Database that corresponds only to the `abi` user, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val userRef = rootRef.child("User").child("abi")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val name = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String::class.java)
        Log.d("TAG", name)
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

In the same way, you can also get the values of the other fields. The result in the logcat will be:

```
Abilashini
```

Comment: You're very welcome, Abi.

Comment: but i can"t add other feilds. only can add one tag

Comment: Then simply use `val emailAddress = dataSnapshot.child("emailAddress").getValue(String::class.java)`.

Comment: App get closed. I updated code in Question.

Comment: It's most likely because of type of your fields. So please change `val age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String::class.java)` into `val age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(Long::class.java)` and `val phone = dataSnapshot.child("phoneNo").getValue(String::class.java)` into `val phone = dataSnapshot.child("phoneNo").getValue(Long::class.java)`

Comment: Ohh Yaaa. I forgot to Change it. Now it works properly. Thank you so much